# How to read csv in parallel and write in Cassandra in parallel for achieving high throughput?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cassandra, dask

I have tried using `execute`, `execute_async` and `execute_concurrent` in Cassandra but for reading 10M rows, I could index them in Cassandra in no less than 55 mins. Note that I have had set the concurrent threads to 1000, tuned the YAML file's concurrent read and write limits as well (to 10000). I have tried replication factor 0, 1, 2 while creating the cluster. None could index the file in less time. So, I decided that instead of reading the csv sequentially, appending it in a list and then writing to Cassandra in batch, concurrent mode or in async mode, how about reading the CSV in parallel?! Hence, I used dask to read the csv file of 10M rows.

```
import json
import logging
from datetime import datetime
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.multiprocessing
import sys
import json

import pandas as pd
from cassandra import ConsistencyLevel, WriteTimeout
from cassandra.cluster import BatchStatement, Cluster
from cassandra.query import SimpleStatement
from cassandra.concurrent import execute_concurrent, execute_concurrent_with_args


class PythonCassandraExample:
    def __init__(self, version):
        self.cluster = None
        self.session = None
        self.keyspace = None
        self.log = None
        self.version = version

    def __del__(self):
        self.cluster.shutdown()

    def createsession(self):
        self.cluster = Cluster(['localhost'], connect_timeout=50)
        self.session = self.cluster.connect(self.keyspace)

    def getsession(self):
        return self.session

    # How about Adding some log info to see what went wrong
    def setlogger(self):
        log = logging.getLogger()
        log.setLevel('INFO')
        handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
            "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s"))
        log.addHandler(handler)
        self.log = log
    # Create Keyspace based on Given Name

    def handle_error(self, exception):
        self.log.error("Failed to fetch user info: %s", exception)


    def createkeyspace(self, keyspace):
        """
        :param keyspace:  The Name of Keyspace to be created
        :return:
        """
        # Before we create new lets check if exiting keyspace; we will drop that and create new
        rows = self.session.execute(
            "SELECT keyspace_name FROM system_schema.keyspaces")
        if keyspace in [row[0] for row in rows]:
            self.log.info("dropping existing keyspace...")
            self.session.execute("DROP KEYSPACE " + keyspace)

        self.log.info("creating keyspace...")
        self.session.execute("""
                CREATE KEYSPACE %s
                WITH replication = { 'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '3' }
                """ % keyspace)

        self.log.info("setting keyspace...")
        self.session.set_keyspace(keyspace)

    def create_table(self, table_name):
        self.table_name = table_name
        c_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} (id varchar, version varchar, row varchar, PRIMARY KEY(id, version));".format(
            self.table_name)
        print("Query for creating table is: {}".format(c_sql))
        self.session.execute(c_sql)
        self.log.info("DP Table Created !!!")
        self.insert_sql = self.session.prepare(
            (
                "INSERT INTO  {} ({}, {}, {}) VALUES (?,?,?)"
            ).format(
                self.table_name, "id", "version", "row"
            )
        )

    # lets do some batch insert
    def insert_data(self, key, version, row):
        self.session.execute(
            self.insert_sql, [key, version, row]
        )
    @dask.delayed
    def print_a_block(self, d):
        d = d.to_dict(orient='records')
        for row in d:
            key = str(row["0"])
            row = json.dumps(row, default=str)
            self.insert_data(key, self.version, row)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = datetime.utcnow()
    example1 = PythonCassandraExample(version="version_1")
    example1.createsession()
    example1.setlogger()
    example1.createkeyspace('fri_athena_two')
    example1.create_table('TenMillion')
    example1.log.info("Calling compute!")
    df = dd.read_csv("/Users/aviralsrivastava/dev/levelsdb-learning/10gb.csv")
    dask.compute(*[example1.print_a_block(d) for d in df.to_delayed()])
    print(datetime.utcnow() - start_time)
```

Even using dask, all efforts were in vain as an hour passed by and yet, the task of writing rows into Cassandra was yet not completed? What else should I do in order to decrease the time taken?

Comment: Maybe change to a different database engine? Cassandra is known for slow indexing; you could use anything for small dataset like 10M rows; there are modern alternatives; depending on your application / data model, perhaps cassandra is a poor fit?

Comment: I got to have 100 million rows to be inserted daily, at this scale, kyotocabinet is too slow, level db is slow as well. Thoughts?

Comment: This really depends on what you want to do with the data. If those are documents with **tricky indices**, then mongodb or couchdb may be a good fit. If the there are **many "simple" indices**, then MySQL is a great fit. Other option is to **compute index value** at insertion time and store the data in redis, which is blazing fast, but row updates may be painful. If you need **fulltext** search, then it's tricky (check features, prototype to confirm).